# MSF4J integration test

Tags: java, integration-testing, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

Do we have any library for integration test with MSF4J, like we have one for spring boot?

If someone knows about some sample library in github, would be of great help.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't need any 3rd party libraries to do integration tests with MSF4J. You can use `MicroseriveRunner` class and start a server with your service then you can do http call to the particular service in order to do the test. In MSF4J we used that mechanism.
For more information refer following test package.
https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/core/src/test/java/org/wso2/msf4j